# Youtube Analytics API 7DayTotals giving odd result

Tags: ruby, youtube-api

When I hit the youtubeAnalytics API with `{"dimensions": "day"}` I get the result rows:

`[["2013-02-24", 0.0], ["2013-02-22", 8.0], ["2013-02-23", 0.0]]`

However when I change to `{"dimensions": "7DayTotals"}` I get the result rows:

`[["2013-02-24", 8.0], ["2013-02-22", 8.0], ["2013-02-23", 8.0]]`

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? The docs say the result should be the sum of views returned by the date of the last day of the week.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YouTube Analytics API returns rows with rolling 7 day totals when the dimension 7DayTotals is specified.

So the value returned for 2013-02-24 is the sum of the individual days' view counts from 2013-02-18 through 2013-02-24, inclusive. The value for 2013-02-25 is the sum of 2013-02-19 through 2013-02-25.

It's kind of odd, but that's what's going on.